# Getting unknown function specifier "BluePrintImplementableEvent" error while compiling my C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am using UnrealEngine 4.27.2. While Compiling my C++ code i am getting this error " Unknown function specifier "BluePrintImplementableEvent" after creating a UFUNCTION.

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "damageableActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class BASICS_API AdamageableActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AdamageableActor();
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent, Category = "Damage")
    void onTakeAttack();

 

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
    void takeAttack();

};
```

Comment: It should be exactly `BlueprintImplementableEvent`, you have it different in your code.

Comment: @Rotem it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Could you post your output log from visual studio?

Comment: Try to do a full recompile. Sometimes changing UFUNCTION specifiers or their parameters may produce compile errors that will disappear only when recompiling

Comment: The error got fixed by a full recompile. Thank you everyone